# Device can only boot into download mode

Tags: unbricking

I have rooted my Straight Talk Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime (SM-S920L) running with Android 5.0 and while trying to load TWRP recovery I messed up with my device and  now, I can only get into download mode.  It says "Set warranty bit : kernel". Samsung's website doesn't  list my device and it turns out to be a model Samsung makes for the TracFone network, so I am at a dead end.  Using Odin I have tried other firmware with no luck and Samsung Kies is also of no use.

What can I do now to get my phone working again?

Comment: First google search hit sent me to: http://forum.xda-developers.com/grand-prime/development/repo-twrp-galaxy-grand-prime-t3048842

Comment: Please see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: @Rexford That looks like it is only for the `SM-Gxxx` variants, I don't think OP should try it.  Scotty: I found [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/grand-prime/development/rom-download-sm-s920l-straight-talk-usa-t3265004) which claims to have a cobbled-together ROM that will work if you flash it via Odin.  I can't find stock firmware anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall the Samsung drivers from kies then go install odin on pc then download the stock recovery.tar it must be the .tar or it will not work with odin. Then open Odin on pc then plug in phone then click the AP button in Odin then select the .tar file and hit run. All is good.